# How to get TextView value from EditText's OnFocusChange

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm new to android. I'm strucked in the below case. I'm trying to bind the listview with combined TextView, EditText like

```
ItemId   ItemPrice Quantity
----------------------------
TextView TextView  EditText
TextView TextView  EditText
```

While editing the EditText in first row, i can get the edited text onFocusChange of EditText. Even i've to get that ItemId's TextView value of that row.
how can i get it.

```
viewHolder.etItemQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus){
            HashMap<Integer, String> updatedQuantity = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            Integer itemIndex = v.getId();
            String enteredQuantity = ((EditText)v).getText().toString();

            updatedQuantity.put(itemIndex, enteredQuantity);
            editedQuantityList.add(updatedQuantity);

            ((EditText)v).setText(enteredQuantity);
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want `Text`s of `TextView`s that are at the same row with the currently edited `EditText`?

Answer (score 1):

Since I see you  have your EditText in the ViewHolder, I am going to assume that you have the TextView as well. In this case you can reference it inside your callback.

```
viewHolder.getItemQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if(!hasFocus){
                            ...
                            viewHolder.mTextView.setText("some text");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

If not, I guess you can make some assumptions about the structure of your layout. Like getting the parent of the EditText (which you'd make a custom layout) and have it set the value on the proper TextView. Something like:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout
{
    TextView mTextView;
    EditText mEditText;
    public setTextViewText(String text)
    {
        mTextView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

and from your EditTExt callback you can use it like:

```
((MyLayout)editText.getParent()).setTextViewText(...);
```

Of course, a lot more (type) checks. And it also assumes your EditText is direct child of MyLayout.

Comment: Thank you buddy. viewHolder thing is working for this case as you said.

Comment: Great! Does the accept answer button work as well? ;-)